# VB to c++ or c#?

Tags: c#, c++, file, vb6, porting

I am trying to translate this code but I don't understand how to use the GET / PUT part of the code in another language like c++ or c#.

This is the code :

```vb
Private Sub cmd_Click()
Dim i As Integer, a As Integer
a = 10
For i = 1 To a
    Dim file As String
    Open "txt" For Binary As #1
    file = Space(LOF(1))
    Get #1, , file
    Close #1
    Randomize
    Open "txtpath" & "\" & i & "txtname" For Binary As #1
    Put #1, , file
    Put #1, , Rnd
    Close #1
Next i
End Sub
```

*The code could have bug because I replaced variables with plain text.* What I understand is that the code get a file and then save it with some random data added to make it look different than the original. I don't use vb since years and I don't remember anything about it. Can someone help me porting this snippet to c++ or c#?

Answer (score 1):

Get and Put are simply used to read and write binary data from the file.

The program you posted basically does this 10 times for 10 different files.

```
system("copy txt txtpath\\1.txtname"); //just copy the file

//and then append some random junk
FILE *f = fopen("txtpath\\1.txtname", "a");
srand(time(NULL));
float rnd = (double)rand() / RAND_MAX;
fwrite(&rnd, sizeof(rnd), 1, f);
fclose(f);
```

Answer (score 1):

C#

```
private void cmd_Click()
{
   int i, a = 10;
   Random r = new Random();
   for(i = 1; i <= a; i++)
   {
       List<byte> file = new List<byte>();
       file.AddRange(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("txt"));
       file.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes((float)r.NextDouble()));
       System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(String.Format(@"txtpath\{0}txtname", i), file.ToArray());
   }
}
```